# jQuery 3.0 - Animate vs CSS transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Since jQuery 3.0 just dropped, I was wondering if there's a major difference now between using CSS transitions and using the `.animate()` function in jQuery that now relies on requestAnimationFrame?

I'd assume you'd would still want to use CSS transitions if it's not necessary to track when the animation ends and use `.animate()` for when it IS necessary to track but wanted to open the question to see if there's any marked performance differences or reasons for using one over the other.